# First packet isn't SYN

Tags: windows-server-2016, tcp

A Windows Server 2016 in DMZ is calling a time stamp provider service on HTTPS outside the company. The DMZ server is not a high traffic one, making around 2000 calls to the external provider per day. The firewall drops the connection attempt around 100 times a day resulting in a "Socket error 10060" on the Windows server. It turns out that the corporate firewall throws away these packages with the following error:

```
First packet isn't SYN
```

Problems started lately a couple of weeks ago and seemingly nothing has changed on the internal server. I don't think this is an application problem as TCP communication is handled by Windows.

This issue only happens when connecting to that one particular URL, everything else is fine. Even more strange is that 95% of the calls are OK.

Where would you suggest I start looking for the problem? Our server is a physical machine. Could it be a hardware problem (cable, switch port, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

A stateful firewall tracks all connections/sessions in its state table. For that table not to run out of memory tracking old, 'stale' sessions, unused records are eventually aged out and removed from the table.

```
First packet isn't SYN
```

sounds a *lot* like a very slow but still running TCP connection is aged out prematurely on the firewall, making the next attempt to reuse the connection fail and create that message.

I'd try one of these approaches:

- increase the TCP aging period on the firewall
- change the server's configuration to reduce idle connection periods
- try to activate some keepalive option on the connection (your question doesn't go into detail on what it actually is)

Comment: Thanks Zac. In my question I specified we are calling a time stamping service (the sort of time stamps you put on business documents). I cannot do keepalive as connection is to be closed once a time stamp was received. What do you mean by "reduce idle connection periods"? How do I do this on Windows Server? Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel You'd need to tell us a lot more about that (TCP) connection if you want more specific help. Note that applications and protocols above the transport layer are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. They might be on topic on [sf] but please check their help first.